# Search FAQ update: Add the url hack tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3 etc to Advanced Super Ninja Search Options

Tags: feature-request, search

## **MOVE ALONG**

## **THIS ISN'T THE QUESTION YOU'RE LOOKING FOR.**

This url hack really needs to be added to "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options" section on https://stackoverflow.com/search .

It will allow you to show only a bunch of questions with 'any' of the tags not 'and all these tags'.

So you can get things like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line+or+regex+or+ms-windows

and even

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/command-line+or+regex+or+ms-windows+or+ms-dos

which will set all those tabs to be just for those tags.

## PAY NO ATTENTION TO THE MAN BEHIND THE CURTAIN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons we don't enable this so obviously is that you can generate some ENORMOUS queries for us -- imagine doing "show me all questions tagged c# or java".

It's fine for smaller tags, but on big tags it's kind of dangerous.

Comment: Fair enough....thanks for the update!  I'll keep it on the downlow 90)

Comment: Then only return the good questions. Duh!

Comment: I've been ussing this URLs since I found the feature. It's a workaround for the missing "List by Interesting Tags" button. Your answer it's good in pointing out the potencial problems. But I don't think it's a developer answer...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd rather see this implemented as a real feature. I shouldn't have to "hack" the URL to get something done.

Comment: B yeah....that ain't happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack the url this way,

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel or vba?sort=newest&pagesize=50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel%20or%20vba?sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Though I would prefer for the search box to handle it also.

Comment: Does anyone know how to edit this to work in markup?

Comment: Have you tried using `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/'excel'%20or%20'vba'?sort=newest&pagesize=50` as shown with spaces encoded? That's what I get for directly entering the URL in the address bar.

Comment: you don't need those single quotes, they are simply stripped

Comment: @Jeff, thanks, I'll edit that in (or out).